# Angular: invoking a function in one component, with events on another component

Tags: angular, eventemitter, angular-event-emitter

Working with Angular6, let's say I have 2 child components A, B that are both part of parent component P.
I want to use a form input on component A- so once clicked, the string value will pass **and trigger a function** on component B.
something like this perhaps:

```
functionOnB(valueFromA: string) { //some code here; }
```

is this even possible?

I've successfully transmitted data between components using angular's EventEmitter, but is it possible to invoke functions with this data, not just pass the raw information?

Comment: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/ if you scroll down there is an example of sharing data with a service.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A common service can be used to trigger the event/function from another component. For example: ComponentA's click event will call a service method. Then, that service method should emit another event. ComponentB should then subscribe to the service's event emitter. Sample code:
ChildA (HTML):

```
<button (click)="onClick()"></button>
```

ChildA Controller (TS):

```
  onClick() {
    this.commonService.AClicked('Component A is clicked!!');
  }
```

Common Service (TS):

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Output() aClickedEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

AClicked(msg: string) {
  this.aClickedEvent.emit(msg);
}
```

ChildB Controller (TS):

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.commonService.aClickedEvent
    .subscribe((data:string) => {
      console.log('Event message from Component A: ' + data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: is it possible you'll provide a code example for ComponentB? how can a function be subscribed to an event, and not just a variable? with the same @input decorator?

Comment: Event can be emitted with @Output operator.

Comment: Gotcha! thanks for the example, I'm sure it'll sort everything out.

Comment: Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, you can use the @Input decorator in order to pass a Component reference to another Component. In that way you can call ComponentB methods from ComponentA.

For example inside FirstComponent you declare a instance variable of type SecondComponent:

```
 @Input()
 second: SecondComponent;
```

And in your Parent HTML you pass the component reference:

```
 <app-first [second]="second"></app-first>
 <app-second #second></app-second>
```

[Component Interaction Cookbook](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Here you have a working example: 
[Component Interaction Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cy6e69)

Comment: Wow! that really solves the problem in a simple elegant way. no need for emitting events, just passing references around. I now have direct access the other components' methods, variables, and what not.. Thanks!